# Get RoutedEvent Source as grandchild of handler

Tags: c#, wpf, routedevent

I'm handling user input in a WPF application, working with `RoutedEvents` such as `MouseDown`, `MouseMove` etc. I've got a good grip of tunneling and bubbling from [MSDN's Routed Events Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), but I've run into a problem with bubbling events.

As a `MouseDown` event bubbles up to a handler, `MouseButtonEventArgs.Source` gives me the child of the current element from which the event came. Is there any way to get a hold of the child of **that** element? I'm thinking something in the way of `MouseButtonEventArgs.Source.Source`

In this case I'd like to put my input handling as far up in my application as possible, but still get information about the initial element the event came from.

An example below: here the `Grid` named Grandchild is clicked, and I would like to handle the event in `Parent_MouseDown()`. However, in that case all the info I get about the source of the event is about the `grid` named Child. Is there a way to get information about Grandchild from Parent?

```
<Grid x:Name="Parent" MouseDown="Parent_MouseDown">
    <Grid x:Name="Child" MouseDown="Child_MouseDown">
        <Grid x:Name="Grandchild" MouseDown="Grandchild_MouseDown">
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Note that this example is simplified, as in my application these elements are of different classes, and reside in different files. Thanks in advance!

Comment: As @RV1987 suggested, the routed event args should  already point to `GrandChild` as `OriginalSource` if the mouse was correctly hovered on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `MouseButtonEventArgs.OriginalSource` It always point to the original source from where the event bubbled.

Comment: I'll give you the right answer, as it leads me on the right way. My problem now is that the `OriginalSource` is another element, too far down in the element hierarchy :) I'll look into which of my elements/controls sets the `Source` and act accordingly. Thanks!